# Using Swift delegate

Tags: swift, delegates

I am writing a subclass for NSOperation with swift. However, I met a strange problem.

```
 class Downloader : NSOperation, NSURLSessionDelegate,    NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate{}
```

When I add "NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate", it will show an error:"Type 'Downloader'does not conform to protocol 'NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate' "
When I delete it, every thing is Ok.
Do you know WHY?
Thanks, advance!

Comment: You need to implement the methods marked as required in `NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate`

Answer (score 1):

According to apple docs https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate_protocol/index.html

implementing 
URLSession:downloadTask:didFinishDownloadingToURL:
is necessary,

Please make sure that you have implemented it.

Comment: Yeah, It's true. Before I use Object-C, if I don't implement the method, It has no error before  compile. Swift is different from Objcet-C.                                       Thanks!